# What is the problem with my code that makes it repeat 5 times

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My code seem to be repeating 5 times:
cannot find the reason:

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    class App extends Component {
        state = { value: [{ title: "my title", category: "action", replies: "62", views: "26k", activity: "18h" }] };
        render() {
            return (
                <div>{this.state.value ? this.state.value.map(valu => 
                    Object.keys(valu).map((tr, index) => (
                <div key={index}>{valu.title}&emsp;&emsp;{valu.category}&emsp;&emsp;{valu.replies}&emsp;&emsp;{valu.views}&emsp;&emsp;{valu.activity}</div>))) : null}
                </div>);
        }
    } 
    export default App;
```

Comment: Hi Paul, welcome to SO. Your question needs some work. For a start, please format your code. Secondly, don't just dump your code; explain what's going wrong, and what you expect to happen. For more, see [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can you please format this? And be more specific with the problem?

Comment: Are you calling your component 5 times ? or in a loop ...

Comment: i did formated the code, can you please explaine to me why my code is bien repeating 5 time

Comment: no, i want to loop over this to get 1 result not 5 repeating result

Comment: But you have jsx in the loop-what do you expect? If you want to run code in a loop *then* use the result to create your Dom elements.

Comment: i did not get your point @Dave Newton

Comment: how can i loop this into a component to get 1 result not 5 result?

Comment: Get rid of `Object.keys(value).map()`

Comment: @charlietfl, i did remove Object.keys(value).map() but the problem i couldn't access my result into a div or a component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `obj(keys)` (it creates an unnecessary additional loop) and instead just simply `map` over `this.state.value`. Then use a unique property for the `key` (ideally this should be an `id` that was assigned by your database).

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  state = { value: [{ id: "b5dc-58f6-u3ga-fbb4", title: "my title", category: "action", replies: "62", views: "26k", activity: "18h" }] };

  render = () => (
    this.state.value && this.state.value.length > 0 // if value exists and is greater than 0...
      ? this.state.value.map(({ id, title, category, replies, views, activity }) => ( // map over value array and deconstruct the properties (eliminates the need to do value.title, value.category...etc)
          <div key={id}>
             {title}&emsp;&emsp;{category}&emsp;&emsp;{replies}&emsp;&emsp;{views}&emsp;&emsp;{activity}
          </div>
         ))
        : null // otherwise, show null if this.state.value is empty
   )
} 

export default App;
```